# Pesquisa MySQL com filtro select option

Tags: php, mysql

estou com uma dúvida. Tenho uma página php com vários select option para filtrar uma pesquisa no banco de dados. Porém, não consigo de usar os valores selecionados na query. Fiz como um exemplo que vi em outro site, um array para armazenar somente os valores dos select option que foram preenchidos e concatenar esse array na cláusula 'where' da minha query... sem sucesso !

```
$tipoentradalog = post('tipoentradalog');
    $usuario = post('usuario');
    $codcliente = post('codcliente');

    $where = Array();
    if ($tipoentradalog) {
        $where[] = " 'tipoentradalog' = '{$tipoentradalog}'";
    }
    if ($usuario) {
        $where[] = " 'usuario' = '{$usuario}'";
    }

    if ($codcliente) {
        $where[] = " 'codcliente' = '{$codcliente}'";
    }

$sql = "select
                            l.datacriacao,
                            tl.nome as tipo,
                            l.descricao,
                            cli.nome as cliente,
                            us.nome as usuario,
                            l.codigo
                            from log l
                            inner join cliente cli on cli.codcliente=l.codcliente
                            inner join usuario us on us.codusuario=l.codusuario
                            inner join empresa emp on emp.codempresa=l.codempresa
                            inner join tipoentradalog tl on tl.codtipoentradalog=l.codtipoentradalog;";
            if(sizeof($where)) {
                $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
            }
            $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);
```

Alguém sabe me ajudar ? Obrigada

Comment: use $_POST ao invés de post, acho que o primeiro problema é esse.

Comment: Então, aqui onde trabalho já temos uma função definida para os métodos post e get... acho que é pra evitar sql injection rs usei esse post em outras partes do código e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Quais são os outros problemas ? rsrs sou nova com programação web

Comment: tente usar a sintaxe `alias`.`coluna`. Você está usando alias para as tabelas e para o select mas não para as condições. Alguma coluna que apareça em mais de uma tabela pode estar gerando uma exceção.

Comment: Richard, tentei usar esse esquema do alias mas não rolou... Quando seleciono os filtros, aparece o seguinte erro diz: 'WHERE 'tl.nome' = '46' AND 'cli.nome' = '172808''... acho que ele tá pegando as chaves primarias  dos registros que preciso ao invés do campo que eu quero mostrar... como mudo isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você colocou **aspa simples** no nome dos campos, e isso faz com que faça uma comparação inválida.

Corrija conforme abaixo, que sua query irá funcionar:

```
if ($tipoentradalog) {
        $where[] = " tipoentradalog = '{$tipoentradalog}'";
}
if ($usuario) {
        $where[] = " usuario = '{$usuario}'";
}
if ($codcliente) {
        $where[] = " codcliente = '{$codcliente}'";
}
```

Se você quiser colocar aspas, para estes caso, você deve usar a crase:

```
if ($tipoentradalog) {
        $where[] = " `tipoentradalog` = '{$tipoentradalog}'";
}
if ($usuario) {
        $where[] = " `usuario` = '{$usuario}'";
}
if ($codcliente) {
        $where[] = " `codcliente` = '{$codcliente}'";
}
```

Comment: Beleza, funcionou. Obrigada pela ajuda !